# Specify fallback possibilities for file-local variables?

Tags: major-mode, file-local-variables

It is clear from the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables) how to set file variables:

```
-*- mode: modename; var: value; … -*-
```

For example, at the top of my `~/.gitconfig` file, I have

```
# -*- mode: conf; -*-
```

I recently discovered `gitconfig-mode`, which makes this unnecessary, except in the case that this `.gitconfig` is opened in an Emacs install that doesn't have `gitconfig-mode`.

Is there a way to write the file mode specification to have a "fallback" mode, so that `gitconfig-mode` is used if available, otherwise `conf-mode` is used?